# How to give Backward Slide Animation to Fragments with Bottom Navigation Bar in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-animation, android-bottomnav

I have a Bottom Navigation Bar Activity with changing fragments. i have done forward slide animation on fragments using 'setCustomAnimations' function but i want backward slide animations it has the same animation as for forward animation. i am unable to solve it, i have also tried many different solutions but none of them are working. can anyone help me give a solution to this
Here is the Code

```
public class Homepage extends AppCompatActivity {
private BottomNavigationView mainNav;
private FrameLayout mainFrame;

private HomeFragment homeFragment;
private GamesFragment gamesFragment;
private ExerciseFragment exerciseFragment;
private GalleryFragment galleryFragment;
private MoreFragment moreFragment;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_homepage);

    mainNav = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.main_nav);
    mainFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_frame);

    homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
    gamesFragment = new GamesFragment();
    exerciseFragment = new ExerciseFragment();
    galleryFragment = new GalleryFragment();
    moreFragment = new MoreFragment();
    setFragment(homeFragment);

    mainNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.nav_home:
                    setFragment(homeFragment);
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_games:
                    setFragment(gamesFragment);
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_exercise:
                    setFragment(exerciseFragment);
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_gallery:
                    setFragment(galleryFragment);
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_more:
                    setFragment(moreFragment);
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
    });
}


private void setFragment(Fragment fragment){
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right,R.anim.slide_out_left);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}
```

}